# Currency not changing and price conversion not working as well

Tags: multistore, language, magento2.1.5, multicurrency, currency-rates

I have created multilingual website with two different storeviews, one in English and another in Chinese. I can say that I have installed the Chinese language package properly as result is visible.

I have even setup currency for Chinese storeview to Chinese in

> Store>Configuration>General>Currency Setup

I have imported the currency rates from

> Stores>Currency Rates

In this page I have clicked import by selecting Yahoo Finance Exchange from Import Service Dropdown.

On frontend whenever I click Chinese language I can see the change in language in most of the areas but currency is unchanged. '$' sign persists and price also remains the same and product names are same as well.

What else is needed to have a complete multilingual website?